# Changing Permissions on a Windows Share from Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, samba, mac-osx

I haven't the slightest idea is this is possible, though I believe it is not.

I would like a Linux **client** to be able to **change permissions on folders on a Samba share** on an NT (or Windows 2000, or something) server. **Is this possible, assuming the user who is accessing has sufficient privileges?**

If so: From the command-line, how would this happen on OSX and on Linux?

**Note:** For clarity, the server with the share is Windows. The client accessing the share is Linux. Something other than Samba could also be considered, if someone has a better idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are programs that can do this such as RTMSHARE from the Windows Resource Toolkit or SetACL (search sourceforge), but neither would run on OS X or Linux natively.  You could investigate running them in a virtual environment on OS X or Linux.  Alternatively, if the Windows machine you are attempting to modify allows remote login, you could install it and run it remotely.

Comment: Thanks for that. The reason behind the question is that either I will do this from a native process on the Windows box receiving connections via HTTP or a message queue, or from the other process running on Linux. Looks like I'll need an app running on the Windows side.

Comment: alternately these tools might run under WINE (instead of a full virtualmachine).